# how to create octave matrix and fill it with default/initial value

Tags: octave

I'm trying to find the shortest way to code a octave matrix of size **m** x **n**,  and fill it with default/initial value, all in one command .

how can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

Typically, if you're filling it with zeros, then `zeros([M,N])`.
If you're filling it with ones, `ones([M,N])`

For any other value `k`, there's lots of options, e.g..

```
X = k * ones(M,N);
X = repmat( k, M, N);
X = k(ones(M,N));
```

W.r.t, Dror's answer, this is also a nice way, with the caveats that a) it requires assignment (whereas the above can all be used in an operation in-place, without having to assign to a temporary variable), and b) you need to be sure `X` doesn't already exist on your workspace, otherwise you may not be getting what you think you're getting. If you really want to be sure, you'd have to clear X first;

```
clear X; X(1:M, 1:N) = k;
```

I'm sure there are other ways. All the above have different benchmarks; there used to be advice on which to avoid for speed if you're doing this repeatedly inside a for loop (repmat is slower, for instance). Can't remember details now.

Comment: Nice answer! I remember reading a post that compared these various options, but that was for MATLAB from many years ago, and therefore doesn’t apply to Octave not to newer MATLABs.

Answer (score 1):

in just one line of code -

for matrix X with dimensions m x n  and default value v:

```
X(1:m,1:n)=v
```

example (for matrix 2x3 with default value of 5):

```
X(1:2,1:3)=5
```

(Per comment from @Daniel  you may prefix the above creation command with :

```
clear X )
```

Comment: This can easily lead to hard to track errors. If you later want a different sized variable (`X(1:3,1:2)=3`) you might get unintended results. In contrast if you always clear X first, you might waste performance.